# Cant seem to get my font awesome to be linked as CSS with my project

Tags: html, font-awesome

I am trying to use font awesome in my project.

I have followed the instructions on their website on how to download it directly and use it within my project.

Here is how I have included it in my link tags.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/MarkerCluster.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/MarkerCluster.Default.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/leafletJs/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/easy-button.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/css/leaflet.extra-markers.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/css/style.css">
```

My code:

```
          <td class="boldFont"><i class="fas fas-camera-retro fas-lg"></i>Region:</td>
          <td id="region"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="boldFont"><i class="fas fas-camera-retro fas-lg"></i>Subregion:</td>
          <td id="sub-region"></td>
        </tr>                                 
        <tr>
          <td class="boldFont"><i class="fas fa-adjust"></i>Population:</td>
          <td id="population"></td>
        </tr>
```

2 of the three are showing nothing, whilst one of them shows an empty little box (image below)
[image]

What am I doing wrong here exactly?

**//UPDATE//**
Also, when I add a './' at the beginning of the path I get this message:
"GET http://localhost:8090/project1/vendors/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)".

I am not sure if its worth mentioning, but I am running this on XAMPP. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: have you looked at the dev console to see if there are any errors related to files that could not be loaded? The path `vendors/css/` ~ might that be `/vendors/css/` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should place `./` at the beginning of href.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendors/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendors/css/MarkerCluster.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendors/css/MarkerCluster.Default.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendors/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendors/leafletJs/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendors/css/easy-button.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendors/css/leaflet.extra-markers.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./libs/css/style.css">
```

Because a path to the css files in your case is read from the `index.html` file

**Example of directories**

[image]

**XAMMP**

Try to see if XAMMP will go 1 directory

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendors/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendors/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @aleksandar, when I do as you suggest, the console logs "GET http://localhost:8090/project1/vendors/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)". I, not sure if its worth mentioning that I am running this on Xamp. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @user16431107 maybe try using "../" instead of "./" like I suggested if you're using XAMP

Comment: @user16431107 I've updated my answer to cover both cases of directories while using XAMMP

Comment: if the image above depicts the root level and associated sub-folders then the path should begin with `/` rather than `./` or `../` etc as they are directives to navigate up the folder hierarchy.

Comment: A big appreciation towards your responses Aleksandar. I have tried your suggestions but to no avail. I think this may be an issue with XAMPP and one of the port configurations, as I dig deeper on the internet and see that other people have experienced simialr problems. Haven't yet come to a solution.